# Apache .htaccess, subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, phalcon, forum

I have website on Phalcon and everything works fine (I have SSL) but now I would like to have an access to the forum (`https://www.example.com/forum/`) but I have a problem with the `.htaccess` configuration.

Phalcon have the specific config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What is the correct configuration for home domain and `/forum/` folder?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ "http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ "https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}" [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Great! You might want to accept Deadooshka's answer :)

Comment: Hey @Deadooshka, it's frowned upon to post code only answers. Can you add a small explanation of what you did/what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Phalcon's root .htaccess file redirects all traffic to /public folder.
What you need to do is add one more condition to your final rewrite rule. Here is portion of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Force www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Remove trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

    # Forward to public/
    RewriteRule ^(forum)($|/) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This `RewriteRule ^(forum)($|/) - [L]` is the important condition you need to add before `RewriteRule ^.*$ public/$0 [L]`

Also you can add as much as rules you want to allow multiple folders.

```
RewriteRule ^(forum)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(some-other-folder)($|/) - [L]
...
```